# How to match a sequence of 2 numbers (different ranges) where at least one must appear?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have the following regex (using in Angular 2 <- Typescript):

```
 /[0-5]?[0-9]?/
```

For some reason this works perfectly to match any valid minute: 1,2, ..., 59
(i.e. it's **in**valid even if no number is written.. but both number are optional!)

**So, why does this work anyway? How to match [0-5] or [0-9] or [0-5][0-9] but not empty string?**

> Valid inputs are: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...., 59

I tried with {1,2} but this apparently matches even **3 chars**

Comment: What are the valid and invalid inputs? Please clarify. Perhaps, you want `/[0-5]?[0-9]/`?

Comment: Try `[0-5]?[0-9]`. See https://regex101.com/r/pA4nD8/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use

```
[0-5]?[0-9]
```

to match any 2-digit number from `00` to `59`.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA4nD8/1)

Here,

- `[0-5]?` - a character class matching 1 or 0 digits from `0` to `5`
- `[0-9]`  - a character class matching 1 digits from `0` to `9`.

**NOTE**: since the first `[0-5]?` includes a `0`, a leading `0` can be present in the number. If you do not want leading zeros, replace the first character class with `[1-5]?`.

To only match them as standalone numbers, use word boundaries: `\b[0-5]?[0-9]\b`.

To only match *entire* strings that consist of these numbers, use `^`/`$` anchors: `^[0-5]?[0-9]$`

Comment: yes, seems working! thank you (can't accept it right now)

Comment: @dragonmnl Do you want to match `00`, `01`, `02`, etc?

Comment: I added variations of the regex and explained them (I hope). If anyone has any doubts, feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: yes, also 00. it works :) (thanks for the explanations)

Comment: can you just clarify what "standalone" numbers mean? (when taking it from an input in HTML it's always a string. isn't it?)

Comment: By standalone, I meant "whole words", those surrounded with word characters (that is, ASCII letters, digits or `_` symbol. If you need no such behavior, or a more restricted context, you'd need to use other, custom boundaries that you can obtain with lookaheads or optional groups, but I doubt you need that.

Comment: I think the word-boundary answer should be the first thing in this answer, because without it, the regex is able to match strings like `60` as two matches: `6` and `0`

Answer (score 1):

To match numbers in the range of 0 - 59, only the first character should be optional. You should also use word-boundary assertions to keep it from matching 3+ digit numbers:

```
\b[1-5]?[0-9]\b
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH6aJ6/1)

Comment: how is your answer actually different than @Wiktor's one? that works perfectly for me

Comment: @dragonmnl I actually posted this first, I think he made edits to his after he saw mine during the 5 minute grace period.

Comment: I don't mind who answered first :) he gave a very good explanation and the \b doesn't have anything to do with 3+ digits numbers (which in inputs are always strings even if input type=number). but I up voted for the effort!

Comment: Actuallly, I was adding to my question without looking at the post. This answer appears like 39 seconds before I updated my answer, though I went on with updating my later. So, this is a valid alternative answer.

Comment: @dragonmnl If a number appears in the string like `159`, do you want it to still match the `59`? That's what the `\b` prevents.

Comment: ok now I got your point :) that's also right (I'll accept his answer just because it's more complete, hope you understand)

Comment: @dragonmnl Look at my regex demo for clarification. If you remove the `\b` from the regex, it will match `159` and `591`